# Json to Excel (multi level)

Tags: json, excel, vba

I know how to parse JSON to Excel with VBA but I have a problem with multi-level JSON.

Example :

```
{
"Level1": [{
    "String1": "Data1",
    "Level 2": [{
        "String2": "Data2",
        "String3": "Data3",
        "Level3": [{
            "String4": "Data4",
            "String5": "Data5"
        }]
    }]
 }]
}
```

How to get everything?

Comment: The { means a dictionary so you access by key, the [ means a collection so you access by index. "" means a string literal so you read as is. Test the data type and handle as required.

Comment: This answered now?

Answer (score 1):

The `{` means a dictionary so you access by key, the `[` means a collection so you access by index. `""` means a string literal so you read as is. Test the data type and handle as required. Below I use a [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to read in your JSON string from a cell A1. After adding the `.bas` from that link to your project you then add a reference via VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

I use a sub `EmptyDict` which I call recursively to test whether the current object is a dictionary or collection and then loop until I empty each dictionary. For each collection I shift one column to the right.

As mentioned in the comments, you would tailor to the output format you want in the sheet.

---

**The tree structure you are descending looks like:**

[image]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public r As Long, c As Long
Sub readValues()

    Dim json As Object, item As Object
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson([A1])("Level1")(1) 'dictionary

    r = 1: c = 1

    EmptyDict json

End Sub

Public Sub EmptyDict(ByVal dict As Object)

    Dim key As Variant, item As Object

    Select Case TypeName(dict)
    Case "Collection"

    For Each item In dict
        c = c + 1
        r = 1
        EmptyDict item
    Next

    Case "Dictionary"
        For Each key In dict
            If TypeName(dict(key)) = "Collection" Then
                EmptyDict (dict(key))
            Else
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
                    .Cells(r, c) = dict(key)
                End With
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Next

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Note, Tim's VBA/JSON work is now distributed through [VBA-Blocks](https://vba-blocks.com), which makes it easy to keep the JSON parser up-to-date - like you would with a Nuget package in a .NET project.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon   Thank you. I have got to get my head around it so I start refering to that.